# ruby undefined method string for TempFile?

Tags: ruby, api

I have been trying to use the ticketmaster api to obtain some data. However, it throws an error when I try to run the code. I do not know why the error is popping up. I do not know if it is because of the url that I gave. Open method accept the url as string so I converted to string and this url is working in postman if I try. The exact error is

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/delegate.rb:87:in `method_missing': u
ndefined method `string' for #<Tempfile:0x28c2d50> (NoMethodError)
        from test.rb:20:in `connection'
        from test.rb:47:in `<main>'
```

and my code is ;

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'openssl'
require 'json'

class Test
  #silence_warnings do
    OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE  #unless Rails.env.production?
  #end

  def initialize()
    @url="https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/events.json?apikey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXT&city=Binghamton" 
  end

  def connection
    puts "url", @url
    result=open(@url)
    response_status=result.status
    #putstus
    if(response_status[0]=="200")
      @body=JSON.parse(result.string)
      puts("Status is "+ response_status[0],"Server Message is "+ response_status[1])
      return @body
    else
      connection_error
      puts("Status is ", response_status[0])
    end
  end

  def connection_error
    puts "Connection error with the api"
  end


  def silence_warnings
    with_warnings(nil) { yield }
  end

  def get_content
    raise notImplementedMethod
  end



end

a=Test.new
a.connection
```

Comment: just use `result.read` instead of `result.string`. Also, you shouldn't include your api key in the question.

Comment: @maxpleaner Thanks a lot, it worked.The api key was free so I thought that was okay but you are right.